# Conditional Format Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I think I developed a brain lock. I have a conditional format formula comparing 2 cells. I need it to color red if the difference is >3¢ or < -3¢.

Here is what I have tried and so far these do not work:

- =(D19-F19)<>3
- =OR(D19-F19<-3,D19-F19>3)
- =abs(D19-F19)<>3

  Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Your values in D19 & F19 could be formatted as Text. Just try this as well and check if it works  =OR(VALUE($D$19)-VALUE($F$19)<-3,VALUE($D$19)-VALUE($F$19)>3)

Comment: What is the format of your values? If it's text, does it contain any other characters besides numbers? What is the result if you place your formulas in cells instead of conditional formatting?

Answer (score 2):

The following will evaluate as True if the difference is greater than 3:

```
=ABS(E17-F17)>3
```

Example:

```
Num 1   Num 2   Test
     3      -4  TRUE
     3      -3  TRUE
     3      -2  TRUE
     3      -1  TRUE
     3       0  FALSE
     3       1  FALSE
     3       2  FALSE
     3       3  FALSE
     3       4  FALSE
     3       5  FALSE
     3       6  FALSE
     3       7  TRUE
     3       8  TRUE
     3       9  TRUE
```

Your first example ( =(D19-F19)<>3 ) only evaluates as False for a difference of exactly 3.

Your second example ( =OR(D19-F19<-3,D19-F19>3) ) should have worked. Maybe you entered your data with the ¢ symbol in the cell? In this case, because the cells contain both numbers and text, you can't use them in formulas. Take out the "¢" so you only have numbers in the cells. Write in a heading above the numbers what the data units are. EG:

```
Cost_1   Cost_2   Difference
(¢)       (¢)      (¢)
 3         15       12
 0          2        2
```

Your third example ( =abs(D19-F19)<>3 ) only evaluates as False when the difference is exactly 3 or -3